# My Windows freezes for a few seconds when resolution changes

Tags: windows-7, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card, lag

As title, my Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit freezes for a few seconds (around 2 to 3 seconds) if a resolution changes or recovered from black screen. For instance, changing NVIDIA settings will cause the screen black for 1 to 2 seconds, which is pretty normal to everyone but my screen will freeze for 2 to 3 seconds.

**What is mean by "Freeze"**

When I try to move my cursor or type something, the screen is keep its status, no any feedback, but after the freeze, my cursor will "teleport" to the position where I wanted it to be (for instance, I would like my cursor to go to the Windows Menu, i.e. left hand bottom corner, after the freeze my cursor is already pointing at the Windows icon).

But this is really disturbing me, although it will automatically teleport to the position, it will be performed after the freeze instead of instantly. For a full screen game, this is not good. If I am playing CS, I probably being killed cause I can't move my mouse instantly.

It doesn't look like this is caused by a virus because rather than this issue, my PC is seemingly fine. It's there some application will cause this issue?

**PC Specification**

ASROCK B85M PRO 4
INTEL CORE I5-4600
KINGSTON DDR3-1600 4GB X 4
PLEXTOR M5P 128GB SSD
WESTERN DIGITAL BLUE 1TB 7200RPM
MSI GAMING X GTX 1080 8GB
FSP RADIER 550W 80+ SILVER PSU

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is normal. Best thing I do to avoid it, is to play my games on the same resolution as my desktop.

Comment: NVidia drivers up to date?

Comment: @davidbaumann, yes, my NVIDIA driver is up to date.